# Starting gcc.exe process in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, gcc, process

I'm working on developing an IDE for C/C++ using VB.NET. I need to make sure the programs are compiled when the user clicks on "Compile" menu item and redirect any errors to GUI. I've written the following code

```
 Private Sub CompileToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CompileToolStripMenuItem.Click
 Dim comp As New Process
    comp.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe"
    comp.StartInfo.Arguments = tabc.SelectedTab.Text 
    comp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    comp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    comp.Start()
    Dim msg As String = comp.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
    MsgBox(msg)
    comp.WaitForExit()
    comp.Close()
End Sub
```

The Argument sent is the absolute path of the file (tabc is a TabControl and several TabPages are added to the TabControl). But when I try to compile, a blank console window appears indicating the process has started but the file doesn't compile. I've set the "PATH" variable in the Environment Variables to the bin folder of MinGW but it still makes no difference. When I try to compile the program manually from CMD, there is no program and gcc works properly. Is there any problem with my code?

Comment: does it show the msgbox?

Comment: Yes. It shows a empty message box presumably because the msg variable is an empty string.

Comment: WHat do you get if you read StandardError